# exact match in regrex when using vim, man, or less

Tags: vim, regular-expression

when using vim, man, or less, I want to do some exact match  in regrex

for example, when using man, I want to check the argument '-c'

if I use

```
  /'-c'
```

the matching could be -cim -covert......blabla

but I only want to match '-c'

how to do the exact matching? 
thanks!

Comment: `-c\b` see [How do I perform a exact match in man page?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156054/how-do-i-perform-a-exact-match-in-man-page/1156060#1156060)

Answer (score 5):

A shorter vim expression to ensure no characters precede or follow

```
/\(^\|\s\)\@<=-c\>
```

The man/less equivalent:

```
/(^|\s)-c\b
```

Additional explanation (Vim):

Probably the most useful part of the Vim regular expression is `-c\>` which simply says "Look for '-c', but only if no letters come right after". Most of the time, you can probably get away with just searching with `/-c\>`, but for the sake of completeness, I included an expression to check what comes before the '-c'. That expression is `\(^\|\s\)\@<=`, which looks complicated just because Vim's regular expression syntax is a bit more verbose (in that it requires you to escape grouping parentheses and the 'or' pipe). The expression `\(^\|\s\)` means "The beginning of a line or a whitespace character". When you put `\@<=` after it, it means "Don't really match that, just make sure it comes before the next part of the regular expression" (which is only really useful for search-and-replace operations). Practically speaking, you likely don't need the `\@<=` part. You could shorten it further by omitting that and adding `\v`, which tells Vim you won't be escaping fancy syntax. That would look like `/\v(^|\s)-c>`.

Explanation of the man/less equivalent:

Much simpler. For the regular expression syntax used by less (which is the default man pager), `\b` is the same as Vim's `\>`, and you don't need to escape the parentheses or pipe character. It just looks for the string '-c' which occurs at the beginning of the line or immediately after a whitespace character and makes sure no other letters come after.

Answer (score 2):

In `vim`, use

```
/\(^\|\s\)-c\($\|\s\)
```

In `less`:

```
/(^|\s)-c($|\s\)
```

You could use `isk` and word boundaries in vim, but this would also match other things that might be options; it's safer to explicitly look for blanks.

Comment: I tried in the man page, it doesnt work

Comment: @user138126 See my update, should better fit your use case.

Comment: wow, it is so complex, can you explain it a bit or are there any good related articles on how these scripts can represent '-c'