# How do you search through flags in the manpages?

Tags: regular-expression, man, less

Whenever I search the manpages, I'm almost always trying to find out what's going on with a specific flag. For example, when searching the man pages for [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/getting-started.html) I was searching the for `-f` flag. I'm not sure how to say, quickly get to the flag which is here:

```
OPTIONS
   General options
       -f FORMAT, -r FORMAT, --from=FORMAT, --read=FORMAT
```

and filter out stuff like:

```
iconv -t utf-8 input.txt | pandoc | iconv -f utf-8
```

or

```
pandoc -f markdown -t latex hello.txt
```

I've tried searching for `/-f`, and I've looked at [another post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67063/exact-match-in-regrex-when-using-vim-man-or-less) and tried `(^|\s)-f($|\s\)` but it was invalid. So I'm wondering how do you quickly search less for "only the flag `-f`"?

Would love your thoughts or some other tool that you use to quickly go through documentation

Comment: first, good for you for using the man pages!  i'd humbly suggest starting with looking for an OPTIONS section (forward slash to activate search then type uppercase:  OPTIONS).   in your search for -f be sure to include a space after it (without quotes):  '-f ', finally try the command itself with an '-h', and perhaps pipe to grep:  pandoc -h | grep -A 3 '\-f '

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! Searching for 'OPTIONS' then `-f ` with the space helps, but then I tried reading the reading the man pages for `grep` to figure out what `-A` was and missed it because grep uses `DESCRIPTION` to put it's flags instead of OPTIONS ;). Is there any rhyme or reason for when a command uses one or the other? Also I like piping the help into grep, I'm going to mess around with it more, and maybe make a script out of it, would love your feedback when I do

Answer (score 2):

One reasonably convenient, if not perfect, approach is to rely on the fact that the definition of an option usually involves that option being at the start of a line preceded only by spaces, so you can type:

```
/^ *-f
```

If you want to search for a long option, you might find that there's a short option before it, so you could type this instead:

```
/^ *-.*-from
```

While it may be possible to get a bit more accurate than this, for interactive use you normally want something quick and easy to remember.